# .NET: Parsing localized currency

Tags: c#, .net, localization

Let's say I have a `string`, and that `string`'s value is an amount of money, localized. By localized, I mean that if the country may use commas instead of decimal points, for example. (That's just one localization difference I know if.)

How can I parse one of these `string`s into their `decimal`s numeric equivalents? Will `decimal.TryParse()` recognize localized formatting? How do I specify the `CultureInfo` with `TryParse()`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is an example of `decimal.TryParse` with a specified `CultureInfo` (Swedish in this case):

```
string s = "10,95";
decimal d;
if (decimal.TryParse(s, NumberStyles.Number, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("sv-SE"),out d))
{
    Console.WriteLine(d);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The decimal.TryParse comes with 2 overloads. One of them takes the culture info as argument (the CultureInfo implements IFormatProvider):

```
System.Decimal.TryParse(string s, System.Globalization.NumberStyles style, System.IFormatProvider provider, out decimal result)
```

The other one takes much less arguments and uses the systems CultureInfo:

```
System.Decimal.TryParse(string s, out decimal result)
```

I'm not completly sure, but I think you could set the current system culture by:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("sv-SE");
```