# How can I parse a numeric string with the euro currency symbol?

Tags: c#, .net

I can't get the decimal.TryParse method to work for currency with the euro symbol. I've tried placing the symbol at the end and after a space to no avail. I've also tried different cultures ("fr-FR", "de-DE") and number styles ("Any" combines them all except hexadecimal). The method fails despite the culture showing a matching currency symbol. [Parse value with Currency symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36001525/parse-value-with-currency-symbol) SO solution does not work.

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var value = "€5,432,109.876";
        var cultureInfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-DE");

        decimal result;

        if (!decimal.TryParse(value, NumberStyles.Any, cultureInfo, out result))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Unable to parse '{0}' as a number using the '{1}' culture with currency symbol '{2}'.", value, cultureInfo.IetfLanguageTag, cultureInfo.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol));
            
            return;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(result.ToString(cultureInfo));
    }   
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DlLarf) with the above.

**UPDATE**

IMHO the suggested [.NET: Parsing localized currency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107674/net-parsing-localized-currency) and the other one I looked into don't expand on how the root of the problem is that the culture must match *all* aspects of the numeric format--thanks to @Zero0 and @Dai for expanding as much on the comments and accepted answer.

Not that it wasn't ignorance of other currency formats on my part, but to see the question down-voted hints at little tolerance for error in this space. I'll keep the question posted given I found value in the answer and comments--others might as well.

Comment: `de-DE` and `fr-FR` won't work because they use dots instead of commas for digit-grouping.

Comment: You would need to use a culture that matches the format of the string you're trying to parse. Your formatted string doesn't match the `de-DE` culture you're trying to use. Just use the correct culture for the string. See duplicate.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889694/method-to-parse-decimals-with-various-decimal-radix-separators and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9160059/set-up-dot-instead-of-comma-in-numeric-values for additional inspiration.

Comment: If your Input is forced on you you may be looking for this detail:              cultureInfo.NumberFormat.CurrencyPositivePattern = 0;  // begining no space
            cultureInfo.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = "."; // force decimal as period
            cultureInfo.NumberFormat.CurrencyGroupSeparator = ","; // force thousands as comma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

`var cultureInfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-DE");`

to

`var cultureInfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-IE");`

Output:

> 5432109.876

Edit:

As mentioned in the comments this works because of the comma digit grouping of the culture.  This answer happens to match (so it works), but I agree it's also important to note why this culture works where others don't.

Comment: While this *works* (because Ireland uses English-style commas for digit-grouping), do we know the number is actually from Ireland and not some other culture? I feel a better solution would be to use a specially configured `NumberFormatInfo` object for the `IFormatInfo` parameter rather than an entire `CultureInfo`.

Comment: I see your point. The short answer works—thanks! The long answer is kinda “you must match *all* aspects of the number to the specific culture”—also thanks!